# three20 and iOS 6 not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, three20

I was just trying out a project of mine which had Three20 in it and it seems that it doesn't compile/gives me build error. Seems like it's because some of the UITouch interface has changed. Wonder if there's a quick fix to do this?

Seems like here is the issue:

> UITouch ivars have been removed of the iOS 6 SDK headers: private API
>   access in UIViewAdditions breaks the build on iOS 6.

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but Three20 hasn't been updated in over a year and even Facebook, who it was developed for and by, has stopped using it. That's a pretty clear sign that you should probably start moving away from it as well.

Comment: Isn't iOS 6 under NDA anyway?

Comment: I agree with mark, time to move away from three20. I think we've gotten away with three20 on iOS6 with the skin of our teeth, but I don't think it will survive iOS7 .. I'm just about to begin a complete rebuild of my app which is completely reliant on three20 so that I don't end up screwed when iOS7 comes out. Painful, but necessary

Comment: Anyone have any recommended alternatives to Three20?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[This patch on GitHub](https://github.com/cogenta/three20-1.0.5/commit/be70e1ff3965c0ff4f7598bf5213349629a27540) seems like it fixes this problem when using Three20 under iOS 6.

Basically the patch is to update `src/Three20UI/Headers/UIViewAdditions.h` and `src/Three20UI/Headers/UIViewAdditions.m` and change all references of

```
#ifdef DEBUG
```

to this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_TOUCHES
```

Comment: Thank you! Updating to new iOS versions ALWAYS breaks three20, this was probably the easiest update yet thanks to your info.

Comment: Thank you for this! For anyone like me that wants to keep their submodules sanitary, I've created a branch in my fork with this patch: https://github.com/cglong/three20/tree/ios6