# Three20 and iOS 6 error compiling for armv7s architecture

Tags: three20, ios6, xcode4.5

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours and have googled everything about it but am not finding any solutions.

I've just updated to Xcode 4.5 with SDK 6 and my project wich use Three20 lib is not compiling.

It tells me that some class is not found or valid for armv7s

I've tried many things, any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187148/three20-and-ios-6-not-working) answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Library your using is probably not setup to support iOS6 armv7s architecture. Check Three20 Lib site for an updated version of the library that DOES support armv7s. Or remove that setting from your project Target Build Settings.

Remove armv7s from the Architectures list. Delete all of them and simply type back armv7.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cant run on my iOS 6 device if I do that, right ?

Comment: Sure you can. I'm doing that on ALL my devices running iOS. I released production software to iOS Store that is running on 4.x - 6.0 and most  hardware types including 5. No problems.